# Retrieve image from Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm looking to retrieve an image from Firestore, to store it on a model when my user logs in.

I successfully stored my image on Firestore, and I retrieved the image URL, and stored the URL on my Users Collection on Firebase.

I have the following model for my **User** on my flutter App:

```
class User {
  String userID;
  File userImage;
  String email;
  String userName;
}
```

I use that same model to upload my user information to firebase during the Signup process.

I'm looking to reuse that model for when my user **logs in**.

After retrieving my user information I do the follow:

```
User _getUserInformation(String userID, Map<String, dynamic> userInformation) {
  User userProfile = User(
    userID: userID, 
    userImage: File.fromUri(userInformation["imageURL"]),//The problem is here
    email: userInformation["email"],
    userName: userInformation["userName"],
  );
  
  return userProfile;
}
```

I cannot retrieve my user image using the URL and the method File.fromUri(), because *I need to store my user image into a **File** type variable*, I need to get the image from the URL and convert it into a **File** type.

how to retrieve an image from Firestore and convert it into a **File** type to store it on my User model?

Or does someone have any suggestion about a different approach? I would prefer not to change my userImage field on my model into a dynamic type or a var type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CachedNetworkImage: [Cached network Image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) like this:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: yourUrl,
        imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) =>
            Container(
              height: 36,
              width: 36,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: imageProvider,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(LineIcons.exclamation),
      );
```